# Ignoring some requirements when installing pip requirements

Tags: python, bash, pip, requirements.txt

I am using `requirements.txt` to install requirements for my virtualenv. I use ansible for deployments which installs requirements on remote hosts.

**Problem:**

1. Ignoring some requirements
2. Ignoring already installed requirements (something like `pip freeze` and if the package shows up, don't install it and don't even upgrade)

**Solutions according to me:**

1. I can grep installed packages and make a `requirements2.txt` having only the ones needed. (Also, remove packages being installed from GIT)
2. I don't understand what `--ignore-installed` would do in this case?
3. Any other solution?

Comment: `pip install` will already ignore anything that's already installed. What do you mean *"ignoring some requirements"*, then how will the code work?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not necessarily true for this task; but often some of the requirements are optional and make installation more troublesome. I often remove some solver (ecos) from cvxpy on windows when i know that i don't need this one. But that requires some understanding of the lib though.

Comment: Have you looked into providing a `setup.py` so you can make it clear which are requirements and which are extras?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I mean that I want to waste less time installing and checking requirements. It just goes, fetches the newly added requirement and then installs it. 

No I haven't tried the setup.py thingy. Will that help in this case?

Answer (score 3):

For selective dependencies installing, the only way is indeed to grep/filter the `requirements.txt` file according to your criteria. However, there are few ready solutions that might be of use:

---

If you have a virtualenv and only need to quickly upgrade it to the new requirements or version restrictions, but do not upgrade if the existing packages meet the criteria, you can use

```
pip install -U --upgrade-strategy=only-if-needed  ...
```

As the manual says:

> `--upgrade-strategy <upgrade_strategy>`
>   Determines how dependency upgrading should be handled. "eager" - dependencies are upgraded
>   regardless of whether the currently installed version satisfies the
>   requirements of the upgraded package(s). "only-if-needed" -  are
>   upgraded only when they do not satisfy the requirements of the
>   upgraded package(s).

---

For the optional dependencies, the typical solution is the setuptools' [extra requirements](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies). For example, I use it for the development & doc-building requirements:

```
# setup.py
setup(
    ...,
    extras_require={
        'dev': ["pdbpp", "ipython"],
        'doc': ["sphinx"],
    },
)
```

Then you can install it as follows, both from the PyPI/DevPI repos, and locally (as an editable library):

```
pip install mylib[dev]
pip install mylib[doc]
pip install -e .[doc,dev]
```

You can define any names for the "extra modes" with optional dependencies.